# How to change the default location for data & log files?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio, how can I change the default location for new/restored database data files and log files?

I tried looking in Tools > Options but there's relevant nothing in there.

Answer (score 1):

In your *Object Explorer*, right-click your computer/server's name and choose *Properties*:

[image]

Select *Database Settings* and fill in your new locations:

[image]

If you were to go back into the *Properties* you would see that it won't appear to have changed your settings (it will have reverted back to the original values).

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26070953/1563422), you need to run `services.msc` and restart your SQL Server service:

[image]

Your save locations will now take effect for any new databases created/restored.